# Server-side A/B testing WordPress services on Kubernetes with nginx-ingress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ab-testing

I would like to implement a server-side A/B test on Kubernetes. However I have no idea where to start and what the best strategy is.

I found two ways of doing this, with the nginx `split_client` method https://www.nginx.com/blog/performing-a-b-testing-nginx-plus/

OR with a kubernetes canary deployment: https://blog.gurock.com/implement-ab-testing-using-kubernetes/

Questions:

1. Will the services still be able to autoscale with the canary deployment as replicas numbers are defined for the proper A/B split?
2. Which strategy seems better, is there one I am not aware of?
3. Do you have resources or examples of an A/B website test on Kubernetes?

Answer (score 2):

You could implement  this on ingress level.
Fresh versions of `ingress-nginx` support weight-based canary deployments out of box.
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#canary.

Good example here.
https://medium.com/@domi.stoehr/canary-deployments-on-kubernetes-without-service-mesh-425b7e4cc862